# Linking issue with g++ and glibmm

Tags: c++, std, undefined-reference

I'm trying to compile [gobby](https://gobby.github.io/), and compilation stops with these errors:

```
/usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-slackware-linux/4.9.3/../../../../lib64/libglibmm-2.4.so: undefined reference to `std::out_of_range::out_of_range(char const*)@GLIBCXX_3.4.21'
/usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-slackware-linux/4.9.3/../../../../lib64/libglibmm-2.4.so: undefined reference to `std::underflow_error::underflow_error(char const*)@GLIBCXX_3.4.21'
/usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-slackware-linux/4.9.3/../../../../lib64/libglibmm-2.4.so: undefined reference to `std::overflow_error::overflow_error(char const*)@GLIBCXX_3.4.21'
```

First reaction was checking the link command. It ends like this:

```
... -lgsasl -lgnutls -lgtkmm-3.0 -latkmm-1.6 -lgdkmm-3.0 -lgiomm-2.4 -lpangomm-1.4 **-lglibmm-2.4** -lcairomm-1.0 -lsigc-2.0 -lgtksourceview-3.0 -lgtk-3 -lgdk-3 -lpangocairo-1.0 -lpango-1.0 -latk-1.0 -lcairo-gobject -lcairo -lgdk_pixbuf-2.0 -lgio-2.0 -lgobject-2.0 -lglib-2.0 -linfgtk-0.7 -linftextgtk-0.7 -linftext-0.7 -linfinity-0.7 -lxml2 -lgnutls -lgsasl -lgtk-3 -lgdk-3 -lpangocairo-1.0 -lpango-1.0 -latk-1.0 -lcairo-gobject -lcairo -lgdk_pixbuf-2.0 -lgio-2.0 -lgobject-2.0 -lglib-2.0
```

(I marked the `-lglibmm-2.4` library with `**`. I suspect that's where the identifiers should be defined. To be sure I ran:

```
$ objdump -TC libglibmm-2.4.so.1.3.0 | grep out_of_range
0000000000000000      DF *UND*  0000000000000000  GLIBCXX_3.4.21 std::out_of_range::out_of_range(char const*)
0000000000000000      DF *UND*  0000000000000000  GLIBCXX_3.4 std::out_of_range::~out_of_range()
0000000000000000      DF *UND*  0000000000000000  GLIBCXX_3.4.20 std::__throw_out_of_range_fmt(char const*, ...)
0000000000000000      DO *UND*  0000000000000000  GLIBCXX_3.4 typeinfo for std::out_of_range

$ objdump -TC libglibmm-2.4.so.1.3.0 | grep overflow_error
0000000000000000      DF *UND*  0000000000000000  GLIBCXX_3.4.21 std::overflow_error::overflow_error(char const*)
0000000000000000      DF *UND*  0000000000000000  GLIBCXX_3.4 std::overflow_error::~overflow_error()
0000000000000000      DO *UND*  0000000000000000  GLIBCXX_3.4 typeinfo for std::overflow_error
```

So, they seem to be undefined in the .so file. Where should they be defined then?

Comment: @RinatVeliakhmedov, I just ran ./configure and make - no changes were made to the originals from the tar.gz

Comment: are you linking against something pre-built for a different platform?   That's when I've seen problems like this before.

Comment: @xaxxon, not sure what you are asking - cross-compiling? Everything is 'native', I'm compiling on x86_64, and that's the destination too.

Comment: No, did you download a precompiled library that wasn't compiled especially for your exact platform that you are on?   like grabbing one for a different version of ubuntu than you're running (or whatever)

Comment: @xaxxon Ok. I'm using Slackware, so basically I compile everything. If available, I use the excellent 'recipes' from Slackbuilds.org, but in this case, the gobby version there was somewhat outdated. Sadly, frequently the software I need isn't available there either, so I have to fall back on compiling.

Comment: BTW, the stdc++ library I used was the one in the slackware64-current repository, that was one of the few I didn't compile.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I solved the compilation issue, but this creates another issue:

```
     19 Aug 23 21:39 libstdc++.so        -> libstdc++.so.6.0.20
     18 Sep  3  2016 libstdc++.so.5      -> libstdc++.so.5.0.7
4515618 Jun  5  2013 libstdc++.so.5.0.7
     19 Sep  3  2016 libstdc++.so.6      -> libstdc++.so.6.0.21
 966848 Jul 30  2012 libstdc++.so.6.0.17
1003520 Aug 19  2015 libstdc++.so.6.0.20
1533144 Mar  7  2016 libstdc++.so.6.0.21
```

After I updatedl `libstdc++` a short while ago, the version increased from `6.0.20` to `6.0.21`, Even after manually calling `ldconfig`, `libstdc++.so` still pointed to the `6.0.20` version. Changing this link manually to `6.0.21` solved the problem.

I was under the impression that `ldconfig` should have taken care of this. Neither the man page nor a search revealed the exact algorithm `ldconfig` follows... Am I wrong here?

Comment: No, `ldconfig` does not care about this link. `ldconfig` cares about runtime, i.e. to locate correct libraries when a program gets executed. The link of `libstdc++.so` is only relevant for _link time_ (when your linker produces the program after compilation), but not for runtime.